# Rails PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR: null value in column "id" of relation "sales" violates not-null constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

**Problem**: When trying to save a record (`Sale.create` even), I get this error every time

> PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "id" of relation "sales" violates not-null constraint

**Work-around**: If I drop and re-create my database it fixes the problem. After the work-around it will work for a while until it starts happening again.

**My hypothesis**: Somehow my test database seems to be getting into a state when it "loses" () it's auto-increment of the ID column for at least 1 table.

**Confounding problem**: This didn't happen with SQLite.

**Background**: We know that Rails creates the ID column with auto_increment and internally the database tracks that somewhere.

**Question**: How can I debug this further?

Versions:

- Rails 6.0.3.4
- Ruby 2.7.2
- Postgres 13.1

#### Sale Class

```
class Sale < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :horse_variant, optional: true
  belongs_to :origin_location, optional: true
  has_many :sale_adjustments, dependent: :delete_all
  has_many :fulfillments, dependent: :delete_all
  has_many :fulfillment_orders, dependent: :delete_all
  has_many :refunds, dependent: :delete_all
  enum fulfillment_status: {
    null: 0,
    partial: 1,
    fulfilled: 2,
  }
  scope :unknown_variant, -> { where(horse_variant_id: HorseVariant.unknown_horse_variant_id) }
```

#### Postgres schema dump

```
                                                                  Table "public.sales"
       Column       |              Type              | Collation | Nullable |              Default              | Storage  | Stats target | Description
--------------------+--------------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                 | bigint                         |           | not null | nextval('sales_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              |
 horse_variant_id   | bigint                         |           | not null |                                   | plain    |              |
 origin_location_id | bigint                         |           | not null |                                   | plain    |              |
 quantity           | bigint                         |           | not null |                                   | plain    |              |
 date               | date                           |           | not null |                                   | plain    |              |
 shopify_order_name | character varying              |           | not null |                                   | extended |              |
 shopify_order_id   | bigint                         |           | not null |                                   | plain    |              |
 order_line_item_id | bigint                         |           | not null |                                   | plain    |              |
 created_at         | timestamp(6) without time zone |           | not null |                                   | plain    |              |
 updated_at         | timestamp(6) without time zone |           | not null |                                   | plain    |              |
 discount           | double precision               |           |          |                                   | plain    |              |
 fulfillment_status | integer                        |           |          | 0                                 | plain    |              |
 status             | integer                        |           |          | 0                                 | plain    |              |
Indexes:
    "sales_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_sales_on_date" btree (date)
    "index_sales_on_date_and_horse_variant_id" btree (date, horse_variant_id)
    "index_sales_on_horse_variant_id" btree (horse_variant_id)
    "index_sales_on_order_line_item_id" UNIQUE, btree (order_line_item_id)
    "index_sales_on_origin_location_id" btree (origin_location_id)
    "index_sales_on_shopify_order_id" btree (shopify_order_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_rails_6df22f6f3c" FOREIGN KEY (origin_location_id) REFERENCES origin_locations(id)
    "fk_rails_cab8258b6a" FOREIGN KEY (horse_variant_id) REFERENCES horse_variants(id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "sale_adjustments" CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_19fd8872e1" FOREIGN KEY (sale_id) REFERENCES sales(id)
    TABLE "refunds" CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_4e4e302c3a" FOREIGN KEY (sale_id) REFERENCES sales(id)
    TABLE "fulfillment_orders" CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_8897bbd770" FOREIGN KEY (sale_id) REFERENCES sales(id)
    TABLE "fulfillments" CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_e8f7460348" FOREIGN KEY (sale_id) REFERENCES sales(id)
Access method: heap
```

#### IRB (pry) session

```
[1] pry(main)> Sale.create
W, [2021-04-04T18:57:11.712216 #58350]  WARN -- : Creating scope :test. Overwriting existing method Sale.test.
D, [2021-04-04T18:57:11.782069 #58350] DEBUG -- :    (0.2ms)  BEGIN
D, [2021-04-04T18:57:11.787486 #58350] DEBUG -- :   Sale Create (5.1ms)  INSERT INTO "sales" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2021-04-04 22:57:11 UTC"], ["updated_at", "2021-04-04 22:57:11 UTC"]]
D, [2021-04-04T18:57:11.787842 #58350] DEBUG -- : Query Trace:
      bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
D, [2021-04-04T18:57:11.788096 #58350] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
D, [2021-04-04T18:57:11.788316 #58350] DEBUG -- : Query Trace:
      bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "id" of relation "sales" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 2021-04-04 22:57:11 UTC, 2021-04-04 22:57:11 UTC, null, 0, 0).

from /Users/marcbeaupre/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:675:in `exec_params'
Caused by PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "id" of relation "sales" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 2021-04-04 22:57:11 UTC, 2021-04-04 22:57:11 UTC, null, 0, 0).

from /Users/marcbeaupre/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:675:in `exec_params'
```

Comment: I'd guess that you're explicitly setting `id: nil` somewhere. Some databases will use the default value when you try to insert a NULL `id` but PostgreSQL isn't one of them. So is there anywhere that you try to set the `id`? Possibly even by accident?

Comment: @muistooshort Good guess but no :(. I can replicate it with just

`s = Sale.create`

Comment: @hrdwdmrbl are you using schema.rb or structure.sql to keep your database in sync? I'd try connecting directly to the test DB with `psql` and running `\d+ sales` and seeing if it has a default set for the id column. if it's an integer primary key it should be something like `nextval('sales_id_seq'::regclass)`. compare that to your dev table

Comment: Any hooks in `Sale` that might try to fiddle with the `id`? What SQL does `Sale.create` end up sending to the database?

Comment: Add your `sale.rb` file to the question.  I would guess it's in there somewhere.

Comment: @spike I have posted it in the question

Comment: @muistooshort I do not have any hooks. I also confirmed that I never do any assignment like `id = X` or anything like that. Remember, dropping and re-creating the DB fixes the problem for a while.

Comment: @BenTrewern I have added it. But remember, dropping and re-creating the DB fixes the problem

Comment: The "dropping and re-creating the DB fixes the problem" part is what makes me think you're setting the `id` somewhere: "look for something, don't find it, don't try to set the `id`, but if you do find it then you accidentally set `id: nil`" is the sort of thing that could be fixed by dropping and recreating the database. You could try adding a `def id=(x)` method to try to see what (if anything) is trying to manually set the `id`.

Comment: Also note the "generated by default as identity" in the table definition, that's something relatively new in PostgreSQL. Does the problem also happen if make the `id` column a `serial` or `bigserial` instead?

Comment: Can you look into your rails log file to see what SQL INSERT / UPDATE statement is producing your error?  Also it would be worth updating your PostgreSQL to 13.2 to see if there is a bug there that has been fixed.

Comment: @muistooshort It didn't happen for a while but now it's happening again. I added a "log" from an IRB session which reproduce the issue. I also added `def id=(foo)` and it doesn't get called except when saving succeeds (make sense).

Comment: @BenTrewern See the "log" that I added. It mostly shows the INSERT statement.

Comment: @muistooshort It is definitely getting triggered by an earlier error which is putting the DB into this state. I didn't get the error for a while because I wasn't causing the root-cause error which "breaks" the DB. Now that I did "break" the DB again, all INSERTs fail in this way. 
OH! And I just dumped the table again and this time the `default` for ID is empty!


How could that happen?! 

Comment: Have you tried updating to the latest version of Rails? Also, I see two zeros in the values list for the insert, one of them is presumably the default `fulfillment_status` and the other is probably the `discount`, any idea where the default for the `discount` is coming from?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I added another field with default: 0. I added it to the question

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found that there was a difference in the problematic database

```
xx=> \d xx
                   Table "xx"
   Column   |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default
------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id         | uuid                     |           | not null |
 name       | character varying        |           | not null |
 type       | character varying        |           | not null |
 created_at | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
 updated_at | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
Indexes:
    "xx" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "xx" CONSTRAINT "xx" FOREIGN KEY (xx) REFERENCES xx(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

compared to the correct

```
xx=> \d xx
                                Таблица "xx"
  Столбец   |           Тип            | Правило сортировки | Допустимость NULL |    По умолчанию    
------------+--------------------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------
 id         | uuid                     |                    | not null          | uuid_generate_v4()
 name       | character varying        |                    | not null          | 
 type       | character varying        |                    | not null          | 
 created_at | timestamp with time zone |                    | not null          | 
 updated_at | timestamp with time zone |                    | not null          | 
Индексы:
    "xx" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Ссылки извне:
    TABLE "xx" CONSTRAINT "xx" FOREIGN KEY (xx) REFERENCES xx(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

such a command in rails console helped in the end

```
  tables = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables - %w(schema_migrations)
​
  tables.each do |table_name|
    begin
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("ALTER TABLE #{table_name} ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4();")
    rescue => e
      p " Error -- #{e}"
    end
  end
```

Comment: You can actually see the problem that you were having in your DB schema. In the first case ID had no default, then in the second it does have a default (`uuid_generate_v4()`).
And then in your fix, you alter the table to add the default to fix it.

But, as you can see in my example, my table does have a default (`nextval('sales_id_seq'::regclass)`).

So actually your case is straightforward in that way.

Mine is more complicated because even though there is a default, somehow it's not being used.